# Using libcurl to mimic curl

Tags: curl, libcurl

I am trying to mimic the below line in a C program using libcurl -

```
curl -d "HelloWorld" http://testserver/messaging/topic
```

The above works - I get my message through.

Basically all I want to do is post a simple string to the URL. I've got this (taken from an example) but it just gives me -

IN

JBossWeb/2.0.1.GA - Error report

## HTTP Status 405
-

**type** Status report

**message**

**description** The specified HT
TP method is not allowed for the requested resource ().

#### JBossWeb/2.0.1.GA

OUT

Also, how do I pass the text? - by appending "?HelloWorld" to the URL?

```
#include "curl/curl.h"
void main(int argc,char **argv)
{
fprintf(stderr, "IN\n");
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://testserver/messaging/topic/");
            res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
            if (res != CURLE_OK) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "failed %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
            }
            curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
fprintf(stderr, "OUT\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add "--libcurl example.c" to the command line. Then build that code to an app and run it...

Answer (score 0):

-d implies a POST request so you need to set using curl_easy_setopt

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "HelloWorld");
```